# root user of linux spanning lots of processes of python script uncontrollably

Tags: linux, cron, root

I wrote a python script to work with a message queue and the script was launched by crontab.  I removed from crontab but the root user of my linux system keeps launching it every 9 minutes.

I've rebooted system and restarted cron but this script keeps getting executed.

Any idea how to keep it from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start a cron, service does not stop even if you delete the file in which you have specified the cron.
This link should help:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/313033/how-can-i-see-stop-current-running-crontab-tasks

 
Also, you can also kill your cron by looking its PId, using: ps -e | grep cron-name, then kill -9 PId

Comment: Turns out that I must have invoked and edited crontab using sudo... don't recall doing that but... when I `sudo crontab -e` the timed command was still in there.  I just removed and I'm pretty sure that will do the trick.